# Problems using mean() in R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, filter

I have some issues with the `mean()` function in R. I get this error when running my code:

```
argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA.
```

The function works here:

`data %>% filter(Sex == "M") %>% summarise(mean(weight))`

But does not work here:

`data %>% filter(Sex == "M") %>% mean(weight)`

This code does not work either:

`data %>% mean(weight)`

I would be grateful for any help. Thank you :)

Comment: You should read [here](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/pipe.html) which explains the behavior of the magrittr pipe.  In your failed attempts you are passing a data frame to a function that expects a vector.  You want something like, e.g. `data$weight %>% mean()` or `data %>% filter(Sex == "M") %>% pull(weight) %>% mean()`.

Comment: Your code that fails is equivalent to `mean(data %>% filter(Sex == "M"), weight)`, so you’re attempting to take the mean of a data frame.

Answer (score 1):

use `magrittr`

```r
library(magrittr)
mtcars %$% mean(mpg)
#> [1] 20.09062
```

<sup>Created on 2023-01-11 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: I think this answer conceptually works, but it would be good to add some context so OP knows what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

If you just supply `mean` after the `%>%` pipe, you are basically throwing a data frame into a function that cannot handle it. As Richie pointed out, this is because `mean` is a function that expects a vector, not a data frame (see below). I show below how to do this in base R and dplyr so you can hopefully figure out the difference.

##### Base R Method

If you run `?mean`, the first argument is "x", which has the following listed as what it does:

> An R object. Currently there are methods for **numeric/logical vectors** and **date**, **date-time** and **time interval** objects. Complex vectors are allowed for trim = 0, only.

Since you did not supply data, I used R's `iris` dataset to show why this matters. To circumvent the issue above, the base R way of doing the same thing requires filtering a subset of the data, saving it as a new data frame, and then applying a mean function to the vector of `iris$Sepal.Width`. This way, R understands what you are doing because you are doing the heavy lifting before supplying a vector to the function.

```
#### Summarise by Assignment (Base R) ####
v.iris <- iris[iris$Species == "versicolor",]
mean(v.iris$Sepal.Width)
```

Giving you an unnamed version of the dplyr method:

```
[1] 2.77
```

##### DPLYR Method

Here I show you how to do it in `dplyr` in a cleaner way than you originally attempted. This way you can understand comparatively what the mean function is doing while also giving your tidier output. First, you can load `dplyr`:

```
#### Load Library ####
library(dplyr)
```

Here I did pretty much the same thing you did with the same `iris` data, but assigned it a variable called Mean.Width so it has cleaner naming. The "formula" is basically as follows: 1) take the data 2) pipe an entire dataset into the filter, which selects only the Species vector values that have "versicolor" 3) using this data, assign a variable called "Mean.Width" 4) apply `mean` to the vector `iris$Sepal.Width` pulled from the previous functions to get "Mean.Width."

```
#### Summarise by Assignment (DPLYR Method) ####
iris %>% 
  filter(Species == "versicolor") %>% 
  summarise(Mean.Width = mean(Sepal.Width))
```

Which gives you this:

```
 Mean.Width
1       2.77
```